# How to create array by providing size in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following method in java and works well in my code. But I just want to rewrite my activity to kotlin. 
My java methods:

```
private void testFunction() {
    ImageView[] pics;
    int count = 6;

    pics = new ImageView[count];
}
```

By converting it automatically with Android studio the following fun is produced but with error:

```
private fun testFunction() {
    val pics: Array<ImageView>
    val count = 6

    pics = arrayOfNulls(count)
}
```

How can I archive the same result?

Error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private fun testFunction() {
    val pics: Array<ImageView?> = arrayOfNulls(6)

    // TODO the rest of your test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even shorter:

```
val pics = arrayOfNulls<ImageView?>(6)
```

This takes advantage of Kotlin's type inference and avoids redundancy.